# Electron Forge Package not picking file from node_modules

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am trying to create a spellchecker using

https://github.com/jfmdev/simple-spellchecker

and followed their instructions.

**main.js**

```
var SpellChecker = require("simple-spellchecker");

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // Load dictionary.
  SpellChecker.getDictionary(
    "en-US",
    "./node_modules/simple-spellchecker/dict",
    function (err, result) {
      if (!err) {
        myDictionary = result;
      }
    }
  );
  createWindow();

});

ipcMain.on("test-dictionary", async function (event) {
  try {
    const success = (myDictionary && myDictionary?.wordlist?.length)?true:false;
    return (event.returnValue = { result: {success:success, myDictionary:myDictionary} });
  } catch (error) {
    return (event.returnValue = { result: "from catch block", error: error });
  }
});
```

**renderer.js**

```
btnTestDictionary.addEventListener('click', function(){
 
  var res =  ipcRenderer.sendSync("test-dictionary");
  console.log(res)
  if(res.result && res.result.success){
    alert("Dictionary Working");
    return;
  }
  alert("Dictionary not working");


})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "electron-spellchecker",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Straive Spell Checker",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "electron-forge start",
    "package": "electron-forge package --platform=win32 --arch=x64",
    "make": "electron-forge make"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Straive",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@electron-forge/cli": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-deb": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-rpm": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/maker-zip": "^6.2.1",
    "@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives": "^6.2.1",
    "electron": "^25.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
    "simple-spellchecker": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

This works perfectly fine on developlment (i.e running npm start)

[image]

But after packaging (i.e npm run package)

myDictionary is always null.

[image]

The SpellChecker has error, but not sure how to identify the error.

My inference is, the dic file is not loaded from the node_modules.

Kindly advise.